# JQuery autoplay video on click show

Tags: jquery, html5-video

I'm using JQuery on a navigational panel that operates as click to show/hide. On the "About" panel is small html5 video that I would like to auto start on click-show and stop video on click-hide. 
The id for the "About" panel is:

```
<div class="panel2">
```

Sample code for how the panels function:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".triggerso").click(function(){
    $(this).hide();
    $(".panelso").show("fast");
    $('.panelso').click(function(){ 
    $(this).hide();
    $('.triggerso').show("fast"); });
    $(".panel").hide("slow");
    $(".panel1").hide("slow");
    $(".panel2").hide("slow");
    $(".panel3").hide("slow");
    return false;
});
});
```

Thanks you so much for your help.

Andrea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#video

and the controls attribute:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/video.html#attr-media-controls

probably the media methods ".play()" and ".pause()" will help you

Something like this:

```
var video = $("#myvideo")[0]; // id or class of your <video> tag
if (video.paused) {
    video.play();
}
```

the "[0]" is to get the html element instead of a jQuery object.

Comment: I did try the "autoplay" inside the video tag but the video starts to play when the whole page is loaded — not when the panel2 is clicked. I need to specify autoplay inside the panel2 only and stop or pause the video in panel2 when the panel is closed or hidden. I don't know enough JQuery to know how to incorporate ".play()" and ".pause()" to make this funtion in panel2 only. Thanks so much for your reply.

Comment: I edited the answer with an example. play() and pause() are methods of video DOM element.

Comment: It's getting there. The movie auto starts on click open but when you click to close the panel the movie keeps playing. I put the code underneath "$(".trigger2").click(function(){$(".panel2").toggle("slow"); lines. Thanks for working with me.

Comment: Final code:$(document).ready(function(){
 $(".trigger2").click(function(){
 
  $(".panel2").toggle("slow");
  $('#aboutvid').get(0).play();
  
  $(".panel3").hide("slow");
  $('.triggerso').show("fast");
  $(".panelso").hide("fast");
  $(".panel").hide("slow");
  $(".panel1").hide("slow");
 
  $(".trigger2").click(function(){
  $(".panel2").hide;
  $('#aboutvid').get(0).pause();
  return false;
}); }); });