# Autoplay / Pause when mouseover mouseout JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, autoplay

I have the following problem. Here is the code:

```
<div class="article-content-wrapper>
  <%= video_tag 'Garden.mp4', :class => "video", :controls => true %>
</div>
```

On mouseover I want the video to go on autoplay/resume, and on mouseout, the video to pause.

How I can do that with JQuery? I searched a lot on the JQuery website but I didn't find anything for me. The code I tried didn't work.

[cSlider: stop autoplay on mouseover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14341448/cslider-stop-autoplay-on-mouseover)
or 
[autoplay video in slider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18361157/autoplay-video-in-slider) or [JQuery autoplay video on click show](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6574323/jquery-autoplay-video-on-click-show)

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you please post the actual HTML generated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An easy workaround:

```
$(function(){
    $('.video').on('mouseenter', function(){
        if( this.paused) this.play();
    }).on('mouseleave', function(){
        if( !this.paused) this.pause();
    });
});
```

[Check jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kmsdev/22phtqtg/)

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on({
        mouseenter: function () { this.play(); },
        mouseleave: function () { this.pause(); }
    }, '.video');
});
```

Comment: It's not necessary to use delegated events if your elements didn't load dynamically 

Comment: but it's more generic no?

Comment: Not at all. Each way is for each case. For example, with delegated events you can't use `event.stopPropagation()`, because the event has already delegated all the way up to the document. This can affect performance if your DOM is deep. So you should use them when necessary.

Comment: You are welcome. Please, mark the answer (your own one or mine) as valid if it solved your issue 